# Remove record from database when session is expired

Tags: python, django

My cart is working based on sessions and `Cart` model. When an item is added to the cart the session is created and product added to the `Cart` model.

Delete product from cart is handled by this function:

```
def remove_cart(request, slug):
  cart_id = request.session['cart_id']
  cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
  try:
      product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
      cart.products.remove(product)
      cart.total -= product.price
      cart.save()    
  except Product.DoesNotExist:
      pass
  except:
      pass
  if cart.products.count() < 1:
      cart.delete()
    
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

When the user deletes every item from the cart, the record is deleted from the database so it doesn't store empty records.

The problem is when the user leaves items in the cart and the session expires (for example: user logged out). The record stays in the database and will never be used again, so it just takes up space.

What would I have to do, to delete the `Cart` model, when the session is expired? The `Cart id` corresponds to the session name.

Comment: You could use [`user_logged_out`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_out) signal to clear their cart once they log out.